# stored procedure returns empty table from code behind but returns a table from sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a sql 2008 stored procedure which returns a table.
When I call it from sql query file it selects currect values, but when called from code behind it returns nothing. 
What could be wrong?

**Here is the stored procedure:**

```
Create Procedure getDGMT
(
    @gene varchar(500), @mut int, @patientId varchar(500)
)
As
Begin
    DECLARE @dgmtSelect TABLE(              
                drugGsId int,
                tumorTypeGsId int,
                geneGsID int,
                mutationGsId int,   
                priority int
                             );
    DECLARE @geneID int;    
    DECLARE @tumorID int;   

    select @geneID=geneGsID from gene where name=@gene; 
    select @tumorID=tumorTypeGsId from tumorType t inner join report r on t.name=r.tumorType where r.patientGsId=@patientId

    insert into @dgmtSelect select drugGsId, tumorTypeGsId, geneGsID, mutationGsId, priority from DGMT where tumorTypeGsId=@tumorID and geneGsID=@geneID and mutationGsId=@mut and priority=1
    DECLARE @v XML = (SELECT * FROM @dgmtSelect FOR XML AUTO)

    select * from @dgmtSelect;
End
```

**if I call it like this:**

```
exec getDGMT 'GTA3', 1, '033333336'
```

**it works fine and selects:**

[image]

**but if I call it from code behind like this:**

```
public string getDGMT(int mut, string tumor, string gene)
     {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataTable tbl2 = new DataTable();      

        using (SqlConnection con = connect("GeneSortDB"))
        {
            //string cmdTxt = "select drugGsId, tumorTypeGsId, geneGsID, mutationGsId, priority from DGMT where tumorTypeGsId=@tumorID and geneGsID=@geneID and mutationGsId=@mut and priority=@priority";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getDGMT", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gene", gene);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mut", mut);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patientId", tumor);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priority", 1);

                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }

            }
```

it returns nothing into the datatable (dt)

**here are the variables I get from the client when calling this function:**

[image]

Comment: Try sth like this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@patientId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = tumor` instead of problematic, as reported many times in this site, `AddWithValue`.

Comment: I have tried something similar without any issues however notice how I have implemented my code .. I will post a working example that you can use as a template to follow ..just replace your connection string where I have "yourconnectionstring"

Comment: Your SQL example has 'GTA3' as a parameter, but your .NET example has 'GATA3'.  Does the procedure return a value with 'GATA3' in Management Studio?

Comment: also when you are passing and or using a connection string I would store it in a .Config file and read it from there.. what is this actually `GeneSortDB`

Comment: @dnfield `GATA3` is a param which in his case would equate to `gene` the OP needs to demonstrate the exacat param values that he's passing .. which I believe if he were to refactor his code based on my example which I have actually mocked up and tested on my end .. the OP will see that it works and I added a datagrid to return and display results.. he's hard coding it in the SQL Management to show it returns so if he constructed his code properly it should work regardless of `Add() or AddWithValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SET NOCOUNT ON` on your stored procedure.

It suppresses the `N rows affected` message after your `insert` query. This could generate an additional result set and your client code must process it.